# Updating the version and dumping shared preferences into database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I developed an android app ver 1.0 in which i stored the user data in shared preferences.
Now I am developing ver 2.0 and I have the following questions about updating it

1.How to detect if version 1.0 is already installed? I mean if it is a pure install(direct 2.0 install) or update from 1.0

2.If it is detected as 1.0 I want to dump the shared preferences values into database. Will the shared preferences be overwritten during update? How to prevent this? If they are not overwritten I want to write an activity which loads the values and dumps them into db

1. What parameter should i set so that market gives notification that update is available. Should i set that in android manifest with same keystore?

Please kindly help me out

Thanking You,

ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html) has a part explaining how to update your apps.
Basically you increase the number of your `android:versionCode` in the manifest. You should also change the `android:versionName` field so your users can see it's a different version.

As for your problem with dumping preferences into a database: The preferences allow you to use a default value if a certain preference is not found (when the downloads a fresh install).

I'm not sure if there is a way of detecting wether your application has been installed or not, except if you have something like a database already in your earlier version, then you could just check if it exists or not. Might not be the best practice to solve this tough.